# Google log in integration

Tags: php

I am developing an application and currently want to allow other users to log in using their existing Google account. I have applied the codes based on this post:

http://www.9lessons.info/2011/07/login-with-google-account.html

I have done exactly what is needed, create a table etc, and also changed the URL_CALLBACK. however, I got this error.

> Error: invalid_request.  Error in parsing the OpenID auth request.

I had try to google some information related to this error but couldn't find any solution. any help please?

Comment: anyone? I have stuck for a long time for this one...

Answer (score 5):

I just got this error myself using nodejs's passport library.

For me it was because my return url didn't include my realm.

Bad:

```
{
  returnURL: 'http://dev-url:5000/auth/google/return',
  realm: 'http://dev-url/'
}
```

Good:

```
{
  returnURL: 'http://dev-url:5000/auth/google/return',
  realm: 'http://dev-url:5000/'
}
```

May not be the issue for the php library. But without knowing what the settings are, its hard to provide any sort of help.

Comment: This is what... I was missing in my nodejs app... Thanks...!